# C# linq to entity An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: linq, dictionary

I'm trying to query some records from my database and convert the result into a Dictionary with string key and string value but continually gets the error "An item with the same key has already been added.".

this is my linq query:

```
var random = (from rec in db.tbl_generatedsampledetails
              where rec.genID == id
              select new
              {
                     rec.@operator,
                     rec.internalID
              }).ToDictionary(r => r.@operator, r => r.internalID);
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: It just mean that you have duplicated an entry of a key value which is your `operator`

Comment: Yes, in addition to what @lexeRoy said, you should use r.internalID as Dictionary key. Key is an ID and should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var randomDict = db.tbl_generatedsampledetails
                   .Where(detail => detail.genID == id)
                   .Select(detail => new { detail.internalID, detail.@operator })
                   .ToDictionary(det => det.internalID,
                                 det => det.@operator);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your id is unique or no. To add something in a dictionary you need unique key. I think your key is not unique. if internalID is unique in your database then write the following code given bellow.

```
var random = (from rec in db.tbl_generatedsampledetails
                                                 where rec.genID == id
                                                 select new { rec.@operator, rec.internalID }).ToDictionary(r => r.internalID,r => r.@operator);
```

Comment: hey, thanks! i just got it mixed up. i should have used the internal id as the key instead of the operator. hahaha! thanks. lol XD